# "Leads ... to be" or "leads ... to being"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, sentence

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> He recognizes his strength which, coupled with his naturally extremely short temper, often leads him **to be** rash with his words.

or

> He recognizes his strength which, coupled with his naturally extremely short temper, often leads him **to being** rash with his words.

I feel like the latter variant is correct but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Why such an irrelevantly-extended example context? Just contrast *His strength leads **him to be** rash* with *His strength leads **to him being** rash*. FWIW I'd usually recommend the second form (or *...to **his** being rash*), but it's essentially a stylistic choice.

Comment: Thanks for advice, next time I'll cut the irrelevant parts of the question.

Comment: We always need *context* if you're asking for clarification about a usage. But providing there's *enough* context, it's nearly always a matter of *Less is more*.

Comment: You might well be looking for "his strength… often leads him to be rash…" but that won't stop either of your examples appearing contrived.

Why not work with real text?

Answer (score 1):

> often leads him to be rash with his words

is fine (and preferable to me).

> often leads him to being rash with his words

should really be:

> often leads to his being rash with his words

**Both are acceptable**. I think it's a matter of preference.